# How to handle cloudflare turnstile on form recaptcha with selenium / seleniumbase?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver, seleniumbase

I'm trying to login to this website: https://visa.vfsglobal.com/are/en/fra/login with `selenium`, but I cannot bypass the Cloudflare Turnstile CAPTCHA.

My script uses [seleniumbase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) with undetectable options:

```
with SB(uc=True, uc_cdp_events=True, undetectable=True, undetected=True) as sb:
    sb.open("https://visa.vfsglobal.com/are/en/fra/login")
```

After running the script, even if I click the checkbox manually, it fails:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the script for that:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    sb.driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(
        "https://visa.vfsglobal.com/are/en/fra/login",
        reconnect_time=12
    )
```

That page has a long initial load, so you need to use `uc_open_with_reconnect()` with a longer `reconnect_time` so that the page finishes loading before the driver reconnects. It's one of the methods covered in the UC Mode YouTube video about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dMFI3e85ig

On some forms where clicking the checkbox is required, add these lines into the `with` block:

```py
sb.driver.uc_switch_to_frame("iframe")
sb.driver.uc_click("span.mark")
```

Comment: Thank you very much Michael. It is working and your library is awesome! :)